# Why do i get a KeyError: 'y_yes' when i have just pretty much copy pasted this sagemaker code to practise

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

Why do i get a KeyError: 'y_yes' when i have just pretty much copy pasted this sagemaker code to practise?

```
pd.concat([train_data['y_yes'], train_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1)], axis=1).to_csv('train.csv', index=False, header=False)
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train/train.csv')).upload_file('train.csv')
s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
```

Comment: Did you check that your pandas dataframe has that column? Print it out to be sure :)

Comment: Thanks Julien...i don't know if that's the right cause: Here's the source.https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/